# show and hiding order list

Tags: html, css, dhtml, javascript

String  +

if user click the + sign i want to show some oder list

then  String -

If the user click the - sign i want to hide order list

How to acheive this with javascript  , not using ajax , jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create an id for the ordered list, e.g.

```
<ol id="superId">


</ol>
```

then on javascript

```
function displayOL(enabled) {
  if (enabled) {
     document.getElementById("superId").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("minus").style.display = "block";
     document.getElementById("plus").style.display = "none"; 
  } else {
     document.getElementById("superId").style.display = "block"
     document.getElementById("minus").style.display = "none";
     document.getElementById("plus").style.display = "show";
  }
}
```

then on `anchor` tag

```
<a href="#" onclick="displayOL(true)" id="plus">+</a>

<a href="#" onclick="displayOL(false)" id="minus">-</a>
```

**PS**....I just did a rough implementation in no order....

Comment: I would advise to show the elements by clearing the display instead of setting it to 'block': `.style.display = ''`. That way you don't change inline/block styling of the elements

Answer (score 1):

try this and attached it to your any event, i.e. onclick, onmouseover, etc...:

```
function toggleList(elem){
var theList = document.getElementById(elem);

if(theList.style.display == "none"){
    theList.style.display == "block";
}
else{
    theList.style.display == "none";
}
}
```

This method can be used for anything you want to show/hide. Obviously, you can call the function and variable anything you like that makes sense...